# How to change a variable value within a function without using global variables

Tags: php

I am using a pre-existing Laravel function from a class. I want to pass an array into it and get the updated values when the function has complete. Is there a way to do this without using global variables? Currently `$counts` is not updating outside of this function.

```
    $counts = array(
        'newly_added_count' => 0,
        'updated_count' => 0,
    );

    Excel::load( 'storage/exports/test.xls', function ( $reader ) use($counts) {
        $counts['newly_added_count'] = 100;
        $counts['updated_count'] =100;
    } );
```

Comment: Pass by reference with `use(&$counts)`

Comment: ahhh perfect thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `use` variable by reference, just pass it to `use` with `&`:

```
Excel::load( 'storage/exports/test.xls', function ( $reader ) use(&$counts) {
    $counts['newly_added_count'] = 100;
    $counts['updated_count'] =100;
} );
```